# Is there any way to simplify this global authentication in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, methods, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create a global authentication using _remap method in Codeigniter. Here are the website conditions for accessing the controller/method:

1. Method must be exist.
2. Some controllers can only be accessed if the user/admin have logged in.
3. Some controllers can only be accessed only by admin.

The _remap method is written in MY_Controller which will be inheritated to all the controller. Here is my code:

```
protected $must_login;
protected $must_admin;

public function _remap($method, $param = array())
{
  # Check if method exist
  if (method_exists($this, $method)) 
  {
    # Check whether the user has to be login to access it
    if ($this->must_login)
    {
      # Check whether the user has logged in
      if ($this->auth->is_loggedin()) 
      {
        # Check whether it has to be admin to access it
        if ($this->must_admin) 
        {
          # Check whether it is admin
          if ($this->auth->is_admin()) 
          {
            # Run the method
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $param);
          }
          else
          {
            # Redirecting to login form
            $this->go('auth');
          }
        }
        else
        {
          return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $param);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        $this->go('auth');
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $param);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $this->go('auth');
  }
}
```

The code is working but i feel like it can be simplified. I have tried but it always end up in infinite redirect. Is there any way to simply this method?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this would be much easier to implement by extending CI_Controller. Examples are everywhere here on SO and on the web on how to do this. CI already checks for a valid controller and controller/method and will error404 if not found. You can leverage `$route['404_override']` to accomplish the equivalent to `$this->go('auth');`  Why create a `go` class when CI already has a perfectly acceptable `router` that's very well thought out? This would be a lot more simplified if you simply leveraged the existing framework structure.

Comment: I agree, I think this whole approach, although it could work, is not the most reliable, robust or maintainable method to achieve what is in fact a relatively trivial thing - upon calling a particular controller, is the user allowed access. This authentication can be achieved in one line, and more importantly, the operation of such authentication can be adapted in a much more transparent way. IMHO this is an overworking of the remap function and entirely unnecessary. Again, IMHO, remap is a fallback for edge cases & scenarios, workarounds and fudges. Personally I would avoid useing it for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my preference is usually to put the check right in the constructor, and then return the user or admin with $this->

```
function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();

    if (!$this->user = $this->users->returnUser())
    {
        redirect("userlogin");
    }

}
```

Then $this->user is now available for everything that your controller calls - models and views:

```
echo 'Hello ' . $this->user->first_name . ' ' . $this->user->last_name ;
```

so then lets say you have Admins and a Superadmin. You don't have to check - does this admin have access to this controller? You can just use separate checks in each controller constructor:

```
    if (!$this->admin = $this->admins->returnAdmin())
    {
        redirect("adminlogin");
    }

// Or 
    if (!$this->superAdmin = $this->superadmins->returnSuperAdmin())
    {
        redirect("superadminlogin");
    }
```

This also cleanly separates out where you are redirecting to so they can go to the correct login page. Finally it gives you a quick heads up when you are looking at the controller code - at the top of the page you will immediately know what kind of user should have access to it. Something to consider - would strongly encourage you not to check for login or admin status in your view files. Its much safer to create a few more view files. Your view files should not have the responsibility of determining whether someone is logged in or not. So basically once you have determined what the viewers status is in the constructor - thats it, you don't need to check again until the next controller call.

Comment: Glad it helped! Also if you can please click the checkmark to 'accept this answer' then it will close this thread.